# Check if integer value is part of linear sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a system that adds 20 to an existing number, x, (..-40,-20,0,20,40,60..) every time the user presses a 'Done' button, this increments x by 20, via Ajax, and stores this new value in a database, and shows it change in real time with Ajax.

Though, as this number increments, I struggle to find a way to check whether it satisfies a linear equation with Javascript.

Basically, I want to issue a 'reward' every time the user increments **200** points, since the increment is of 20, I can be sure that it definitely will hit the sequence, which eliminates the need for greater than / less than clauses..

Basically, how do I express:

```
if x = 200n (if x is 200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400...) alert("yay");
```

I really don't get how this is possible with `JavaScript` or `jQuery`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `modulus operator (%)`:

```
if (x % 200 === 0){
    // do what you want here.
}
```

**% (Modulus)**

> The modulus operator is used as follows:
>   var1 % var2
>   The modulus operator returns the first operand modulo the second operand.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/yxM6J/)

---

If `x` can be zero, and you want to exclude this value:

```
if (x && x % 200 === 0){
    // do what you want here.
}
```

Comment: +1, but you may want to add in a check for when `x` is 0, since `0 % 200 === 0`, but I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @JamesAllardice. He wrote he check the value after the ajax, so I think the minimum value is 20, But I'll add a remark. thanks.

Comment: @gdoron - In the first example in the question the value is -40, so I think it can end up as 0. Probably worth noting in any case.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, so `0` can be a valid entry, if he start with `-200`. We need more data from the OP... anyway I added the note, and it's up to him. thanks for your comments!